# UIImage Animation delay Array

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uiviewanimation

i found this code which is very helpful to avoid delay at first animation:

```
NSMutableArray *menuanimationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int aniCount = 1; aniCount < 21; aniCount++) {
    NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"bg%i", aniCount + 1] ofType: @"png"];
    // here is the code to pre-render the image
    UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fileLocation];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameImage.size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
    [frameImage drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [menuanimationImages addObject:renderedImage];
}

settingsBackground.animationImages = menuanimationImages;
```

But i want to use the same image sometimes - can i fill within the code above my array manually via

```
testArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_001.png"],


                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_002.png"],

                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_001.png"],
nil];
```

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Yes you can use the same images

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using this

```
UIImageView * animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,200)];

testArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_001.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_002.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_001.png"],nil];
animTime =3.0;
[animatedImageView setAnimationImages:testArray] ;
animatedImageView.animationDuration =  animTime;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: Yes - but for me it is important to preload my images - so that there will be no delay at first animation...

Comment: you can delay your view to handle that